# How to Pass Data Between Pages using OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo Events

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have two pages in my application. The Navigation follows MainPage > EditPage > MainPage. MainPage is the starting page and edit page may be NavigatedTo upon a button click and NavigatedFrom using the hardware back button. If some action occurs in EditPage, I would like to inform MainPage when the user wishes to return to MainPage. I have referenced http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/passing-values-between-windows but I am not sure how fix the MainPage OnNavigatedTo event accordingly. SO far what I have is as follows

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //If action in EditPage occurred, determine that here
        ??
    }
```

EditPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        //check to see if action occurred in EditPage, and if so, inform MainPage
        if (_wasEdited == true)
        {
            MainPage mp = e.Content as MainPage;
            if (mp != null)
                mp.Parameter = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you just add a prop on the Base of EditPage, and upon navigatedFrom, signal it before navigation.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean?

Comment: You can create a base page for all of your pages. This can help you resolve a lot of things and also you can reuse the same functionalities your pages offer like CRUD.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything like that before. Is there a more simple way? I've used a custom settings class that saves to isolated storage, but saving some sort of Boolean value in this method seems like overkill.

Comment: A base class is more appropriate, i think it'll help you the more you expand your app (in your case add more maps), this keeps those repetitive code isolated on a single class the Maps inherits

Comment: you can use mvvmlight messenger class for sending messages from one page to other page..i thinks it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an App level variable, in your App.xaml.cs

```
public bool isThereAnyChange = false;
```

In your EditPage.xaml.cs, when ever you do a change, update 'isThereAnyChange'.

```
private void updateChangeStatus()
{
    (App.Current as App).isThereAnyChange = true;
}
```

Then in MainPage.xaml.cs chack for above variable.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //If action in EditPage occurred, determine that here
        if((App.Current as App).isThereAnyChange)
              //The change is there do accordingly here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass values between pages you can use querystring or app state variables, and as far as differentiating the navigation is concerned just put up a check on e.URI property of NavigatedTo event argument, that's it

Comment: I've used querystring but only when directly navigating to a new page on a click event. In this case I am only navigating back one page, so can I use querystring in this case using the OnNavigated events? Would you be able to give a quick example?